# Heyzap Ad Mediation, only work for rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, ads, rootview, heyzap

I started using Heyzap today to integrate multiple ad 
networks in my iOS project. The integration went well as shown in the image below.

However, I run into problems while trying to show ads. I get warning messages saying that the ads are getting presented on top of rootviewcontroller and it's not in the view hierarchy right now.

```
*Warning: Attempt to present <GADInterstitialViewController:    0x14f63d9c0> on <TwentyFour.GameEntranceViewController: 0x14f5094c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!*
```

"GameEntranceViewController is my RootViewController"

How can I present ads if it's not for the `rootViewController`? I have my code below, what did I do wrong?

1. In AppDelegate

   ```
   HeyzapAds.startWithPublisherID("publisher_id")
   HZInterstitialAd.fetch()
   ```
2. In `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` in a view controller which is not 
   RootViewController.

   ```
   if HZInterstitialAd.isAvailable() {

     HZInterstitialAd.show()

   }
   ```

Thanks a lot!!!
[image: Mediation Test Suite shown, with multiple networks integrated correctly]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an iOS engineer at Heyzap. You can create an `HZShowOptions` object, set the `viewController` property on it, and pass that to `showWithOptions`:

```
let options:HZShowOptions = HZShowOptions()
options.viewController = self
HZInterstitialAd.showWithOptions(options)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. You are a life saver!